# Select data from one table with id from another

Tags: mysql

so as text is saying I need to grab user id by name from one table and then select count from another table by that ID. is it possible?

---

users table

```
ID | User
```

online table

```
ID
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand your requirements if you showed some sample data, the format of your expected output, what you had tried so far and what problems you are having.

Answer (score 4):

How about something more like:

```
SELECT COUNT(users.id)
FROM users
    INNER JOIN online
        ON online.ID = users.ID
WHERE users.id = 'myuser';
```

Comment: I would expect the SQL engine to optimize away the extra select into a join in the execution plan in most cases, but I agree it is usually best not to go into a sub-select when it can be done more simply.

Comment: From my understanding, this solution is better than the solution with multiple selects because the dbms can do optimizations on the joins.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM online WHERE ID = (SELECT ID FROM users WHERE name = 'myuser')
```